# OrchardCMS duplicated item with same version Number and ContentItemRecord_id

Tags: orchardcms

Yesterday, the person in charge of adding content to our OrchardCMS website suddenly got this error when trying to access the **Content** section in the Dashboard and we can't add any new content any more.

[image]

I've imported a bacpac of the database in production and started locally debugging. When trying to access the **Content** an exception is thrown right here:

[image]

And, if we look in the database, the **Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord** table contains a duplicated item with the same version Number, both are "latest version" and they both have the same ContentItemRecord_id.

[image]

My concern now is how should we fix this without causing any side effect somewhere else, since I don't fully understand how Orchard manages relations between items, parts, and versions.

**Solution proposal:**

It seems natural and obvious to **manually update** the "is latest version" of one of the items to *false* and increment the version number of the latest one.

- Is this solution right or will I cause a side problem?
- Have you experienced this before?
- Do you know if this is caused by a wrong way of defining the model or something I can do to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Just wanted to say I've just started to have this issue too. I'm running two servers in my environment, so I'm thinking it's possibly a double-click problem or possibly something to do with having more than one server. I haven't found the root cause as yet though.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: it is probably due to double clicking the publish button... Small tip and hack: hide publish button on click...

Comment: But, to get around the situation right now, your proposal is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that happened to me once before, it was ugly situation and a lot of debugging had to be done to find the cause.
The only fix I could find back then was to alter/edit/fix the db data manually.

**I must ask**
did that error happen once or does it happen all the time?

Comment: It has just happen once, but our CMS is been live for two weeks, not very old at all.

Comment: You should be worried if it happens all the time, but happened once is the same case I had, just alter the db data and you will be fine.